# How to get and print input type number with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, input, numbers

I want to print an input type number on confirmation page.

```
var displayConfirm = function() {
            $('#tab5 .form-control-static', form).each(function(){
                var input = $('[name="'+$(this).attr("data-display")+'"]', form);
                if (input.is(":radio")) {
                    input = $('[name="'+$(this).attr("data-display")+'"]:checked', form);
                }
                if (input.is(":text") || input.is("textarea")) {
                    $(this).html(input.val());
                } else if (input.is("select")) {
                    $(this).html(input.find('option:selected').text());
                } else if (input.is(":radio") && input.is(":checked")) {
                    $(this).html(input.attr("data-title"));
                } 
            });
        }
```

If I use `input.is(":number")` and `$(this).html(input.val());` it crashes.

Comment: 1) there is no input with the type of "number" in html. 2) show your html, this could clarify what you want to achieve.

Comment: there is `<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">`

Comment: @low_rents: surprise....http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html :P

Comment: @MilindAnantwar ok, but it is maybe so new that his version of jQuery might not know about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it crashed because `:number` is not valid selector.
You need to use attribute equals selector in `.is()` condition:

```
input.is("[type=number]")
```

**Snippet:**

```
else if (input.is("[type=number]")) {
    $(this).html(input.val());
}
```

Comment: BTW, Do I need to change :text to [type:text] ?

Comment: @ArasSerdaroğlu: nop.. jai already mentioned, its perfectly valid as jquery have selector `:text ` for type text

Comment: one more question, I want to show a preview for input file (image) on confirmation page, how to do that?

Comment: You can show them in modal along with confirm button

Comment: I'm listing all my inputs in a single page.

Comment: you can make something like carousal. would be great if you post new question with relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, you can register a jQuery pseudo selector if you wanted to stick with `:number`:

```
$.expr[':'].number = function(el){
  var $el = $(el);
  return $el.prop('tagName').toLowerCase() == 'input' && $el.prop('type') == 'number';
}
```

`.is(':number')` would then work perfectly fine for you.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5njasfqr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#qwe').keyup(function () {
    alert($(this).val());

});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7a5esayb/)

To get value of input element use .val()

Comment: well @pekka i guess OP is doing that. `input.val()`

Comment: @jai correct me if I'm wrong the OP wants to print a number so get the val()

Comment: _If I use `input.is(":number")` and `$(this).html(input.val());` it crashes._

Comment: because the selector is wrong `:number` isnt a selector right?so my answer  is still valid because it is a correct selector and it prints the value of input @Jai what do you think?should i just delete the answer?